# Samsung Smart TV remote app for Windows Phone or Android

Tags: android, windows-phone, samsung-smart-tv, remote-control

For school project I need to develop a mobile application witch will work like a remote control for Samsung Smart TV. I "went" to the samsung official website and forum to search for API of some kind that will help me with development of my application, but there were only tutorials on how to connect your TV app with Samsung's official remote app for android. 
I expect that they don't want or don't need to post an API for that reason because there is already an application for that purpose on market (their official android application).

I found the SamyGO app source code, but when i read it carefully i saw that it uses TV_APP_STRING = iphone..iapp.app (for connection and sending keys to the TV) or something like this, and i thought that the phone is trying to lie the TV that it is actually an iPhone.

I am sorry for this kind of question, but I am begging if someone can help me. Maybe pass a link to some Windows Phone open source solution, maybe other Android open source solution, or maybe explain why SamyGO uses this tehnic (maybe it's the only way).

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Consider narrowing your question to why the SamyGO code works as it does.  The other aspect of your question broadens it a lot and is really an off-topic request for a resource recommendation.